# Transfer a multi column table into a simple form with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine a given table by the following form. For example from a system where someone can rent up to three books (as inventory-numbers)

`table 'rentbooks':`

| name | book1 | book2 | book3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 100 |  |  |
| Bob | 200 | 250 | 400 |
| Claire | 300 | 350 |  |

I'd like to transfer this into a more useful form like this (1 book, 1 row), IDs don't matter:

| name | rentbookid |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 100 |
| Bob | 200 |
| Bob | 250 |
| Bob | 400 |
| Claire | 300 |
| Claire | 350 |

How could the Query be constructed to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select name, book1 from rentbooks where book1 is not null
union all
select name, book2 from rentbooks where book2 is not null
union all
select name, book3 from rentbooks where book3 is not null
```

Result:

```
 name    book1 
 ------- ----- 
 Adam    100   
 Bob     200   
 Claire  300   
 Bob     250   
 Claire  350   
 Bob     400
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vgzwR5zhjdKo5gBmsg114k/0).